# Mvc Linq search doesn't show foreign keys in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to make a search for my index using linq. The search and everything works, but it doesn't show my foreign keys names

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    var formular = from s in db.Formulars.Include(f => f.sagsbehandlere).Include(f => f.medlemmer)
                   let mem = s.medlemmer.forNavn + " " + s.medlemmer.EfterNavn
                   let Sag = s.sagsbehandlere.forNavn + " " + s.sagsbehandlere.EfterNavn
                   where mem.Contains(search) || Sag.Contains(search)
                   select s;

    return View(formular);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="search" />

    <input type="submit" value="search" />
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sagsbehandlere.forNavn)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormularNavn)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.behandled)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MedlemmersId)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sagsbehandlere.forNavn) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sagsbehandlere.EfterNavn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormularNavn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.behandled)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.medlemmer.forNavn) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.medlemmer.EfterNavn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
</tr>
```

but when I search on the index page it doesn't show the included sagsbehandlere.

Best Regards Lin

Comment: what do you have in your view?

Comment: have editted so you can see the view.

Comment: i think its because it doesn't bind the includes to the "var formular".

Comment: The implementation looks correct, is there data in sagsbehandlere and is Formulars and Sagsbehandleres being persisted correctly in the database?

Comment: yes, there is data for both Sagsbehandlere and medlemmer. it just doesn't show in the view. @ChesterCobus

Comment: ok when you debugging is the formular variable populated with sagsbehandlere data before it returns to the view ?

Comment: I believe DisplayFor doesn't bind the model. Have you tried using TextBoxFor or LabelFor ?